# Pasar datos entre ventanas

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, eventos, ventana

Buen día amigos, tengo la siguente duda ¿se puede pasar datos de una ventana hija a una padre? ya sé que se puede pasar datos de una padre a una hija por medio de ajax, ¿pero cómo se hace al contrario?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es algo así de la pequeña a la grande, muchas gracias..

Comment: una forma de hacerlo es usando cookies temporales o localstorage o sessionstorage, que cuando sean detectadas por la ventana padre ejecute un comando.

Comment: Tambien la opcion de @Einer es buena y efectiva

Comment: aqui hay una desmotracion de que lo que dice @Einer es buena opcion http://usefulangle.com/post/4/javascript-communication-parent-child-window

Answer (score 1):

Si la ventana que abres pertenece a tu misma aplicacion web, utiliza el [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener):

> Devuelve una referencia a la ventana que abrió esta ventana actual.

Por ejemplo en tu ventana principal:

```
window.open("url_ventana_de_mi_aplicacion"); // abrimos la ventana

function asignarResultados(resultado)
{
  alert(resultado);
}
```

Entonces para enviarle los datos a la ventana padre desde la otra ventana seria:

```
<script>
 window.opener.asignarResultado("Hola desde la otra ventana");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Por variable GET con javascript

```
function abrirVentana() {
   window.open("ventanaNueva.php?var=data", "popupId", "location=no,menubar=no,titlebar=no,resizable=no,toolbar=no, menubar=no,width=500,height=500");  
}
```

`ventanaNueva.php` es la pagina que procesara tu petición, y `var=data` es la variable con su contenido que mandarás

por ejemplo `ventanaNueva.php?dia=15&mes=12`